# Switching a freshly formatted HDD to another laptop

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, bsod

So here is the situation, sorry for a bit of a long post.

I have one(HP) laptop which harddrive unfortunately recently crashed, while i have another Compaq laptop with worse hardware, but an harddrive that is the exact same model as the HP one.

So what i did was to directly put the working HDD(With Windows 7) from my Compaq over to the HP laptop, but couldn't really do anything, as the PC got a BSOD and crashed whenever i moved the mouse cursor. I searched around for a bit, and decided it was probably due to the OEM Windows 7 edition that HDD had installed, so i decided to do a clean install with the retail version of windows i had on my HP.

However, it doesen't seem to be possible to re-format the harddrive on the HP laptop, due to it lacking a dvd player, and somehow there is a password locking me out from accessing the BIOS, making me unable to switch the boot order to an USB port.

However, what happens when i try to boot up the HP laptop, is that it simply flashes a quick BSOD when the windows 7 screen is showing up, and just restarting.

So what i have tried is to perform the reformat on the Compaq laptop, instantly swap it over to the HP laptop once the installation is complete.

Now, i'm wondering if what i'm doing is possible at all?

And lastly, pardon me for the long post, thought it would be easier to understand with the context. Thanks in advance

Comment: Installing Windows on the Compaq and using it with different hardware on the HP laptop will cause major problems. Figure out the BIOS password on the HP (using [this](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd) or [this](http://dogber1.blogspot.in/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html)), change the boot order, then use a USB-based Windows installer (created with Rufus) to install the OS.

Comment: You have to get this BIOS working. Else you are dead in the water.

Comment: Alright thanks, will try. Have to say it's really annoying to be locked out of my own BIOS

Answer (score 0):

The compaq and the HP most likely have hidden rescue partitiions on their respective hard drives . Which would be nice for rescuing them from BSOD except thenormal media and the rescue media all expect to see different hardware and key confirmation from their former laptops. You could probably make it work given time and patience and media imaging saoftware and poring through Microsoft literature and help sites. But an easier way is probably to get both good advice and rescue discs/new drivwers from the Compaq/HP support people since they are a single place for both brands. They really are good at dealing with and pointing the tiny differences between their products and generic computers. The kinds of differences that have computers balking mysteriously while enthusiasts tearing out their hair and cursing Bill Gates intel and Exerything Adobe ever did until the Enthusiast knows about the tiny feature too.enthusiast hears about the tiny difference too. HP/compaq are pretty nice as far as support help goes. Its worth a look